# Setting custom color palette to raster GeoTIFF file with Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, palette

I have a 16-bit single-band integer *tif* raster, and I am trying to use a custom color palette. There are 2 categories in the raster, plus the no-data value (-999). This raster is calculated and created by a python script. I am able to work with it in QGIS. I used the code below in order to set the default colors but it does not work

```py
import gdal

# specify GeoTIFF file name, open it using GDAL and get the first band
fn = 'C:\\Users\\aantg\\Dropbox\\Webinars\\tmp\\drought_6.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(fn, 1)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# create color table
colors = gdal.ColorTable()

# set color for each value
#set color for each LULC class
colors.SetColorEntry(1, (195,20,0))   #"Dry Season"
colors.SetColorEntry(2, (0,100,0))    #"Wet Season"

# set color table and color interpretation
band.SetRasterColorTable(colors)
band.SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_PaletteIndex)

# close and save file
del band, ds
```

The output is a 3-band raster (RGB) but the values in all bands are the same as the input file.

[image: output rgb file]